# How to tune CSS with Isotope to display top border?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

we are using an Isotope/Masonry based layout and currently have the following problem for our project: Our Isotope element have a border, but this border disappears after Isotope calculates the positioning. in the element.style, Isotope sets top: 0px, while when we manually adjust the value top: 3px the border shows up correctly again.

See attached screenshots:

- Top border is not shown:
  [image: wrong]
- Top border is shown:
  [image: right]
- The CSS sets top: 0px, but top: 3px would show the border nicely:
  [image: isotope top value]

What's going on? How to fix this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, can be solved with:

containerStyle: { position: 'relative', overflow: 'visible' }

Answer (score 1):

You can also use box sizing:

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

And the dimensions of the border will be calculated with the containing element.